# How do I add entries to a NaN field using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a .csv file in which one of the column has text written in Japanese and the adjacent column has to be populated with the translation in English. This is the script that I have written. Google Translate API is working fine on my local environment(tested). However I am unable to populate the blank cells in the dataframe. When I open the dataframe after running the script, i get the same "NaN" values. I am attaching the csv file for reference.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3x1jvkj2j70ocy/sarthak.csv?dl=0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx6Yn.png

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import translate
client = translate.Client()
df = pd.read_csv('sarthak.csv')
total_rows = df.count()
row_num = df.shape[0]
for i in range(row_num):
    text_to_be_translated = df.iloc[i,7]
    location_for_translated_text = df.iloc[i,6]
    try:
        translated_text_dict = client.translate(text_to_be_translated)
        translated_text = str(translated_text_dict['translatedText'])
        df.set_value(i, 6, translated_text, takeable=False)
    except:
        print("not available")
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the df.set_value line.  'tranlated_tex'.  I believe this is throwing you into your except condition every iteration.

Rather than iterating over each row, I would look into using the [apply function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the variable names for this question. My original code does not use the same variable names and does not have typos. I will look into the apply function. Cheers!

Comment: The apply function solved my issue and made my code crisper! Thanks!